# Docker Failed to initialize CoreCLR for DotNet Core 2.2 WebAPI

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I built a .net core webapi in version 2.2. I am building the docker container for it with `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk` I've also tried `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime`. It builds fine but when I run the container it exits almost immediately. The logs say simple

> Failed to initialize CoreCLR

How do I fix this?